# Need help creating an expression in Notepad++

Tags: xml, notepad++

I'm processing a few hundred XML files, and the tool that creates them tends to (annoying) ignore paragraph breaks in the source content. So, you get a lot of this in the XML file:

```
... tradition of storytelling.Advertisers, TV programmers ...
```

See how the sentence ends with "storytelling.Advertisers" with no space?

I need to replace that with:

```
... tradition of storytelling.</p><p>Advertisers, TV programmers ...
```

Can anybody give me a hand with the proper expression to handle this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `Regular expression` box in the `Replace` dialog. Use

```
(.*\.)([A-Z])
```

in the `Find what`, and

```
\1</p><p>\2
```

in the `Replace with`.

Given this text:

```
tradition of storytelling.Advertisers, TV programmers,
tradition of storytelling".Advertisers, TV programmers,
tradition of storytelling'.Advertisers, TV programmers,
tradition of storytelling).Advertisers, TV programmers,
```

`Replace All` using the above values results in

```
tradition of storytelling.</p><p>Advertisers, TV programmers,
tradition of storytelling".</p><p>Advertisers, TV programmers,
tradition of storytelling'.</p><p>Advertisers, TV programmers,
tradition of storytelling).</p><p>Advertisers, TV programmers,
```

Comment: That's fantastic, but it doesn't work with sentences that end with quotes or parenthesis.